# Does Jenkins have anything like TeamCity's service messages?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

TeamCity has a feature that (as near as I can figure) is called "service messages". You can see the documentation [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity). Essentially, it lets me write things like

```
##teamcity[publishArtifacts '<path>']
```

to tell the build server to do things. I like this feature. It lets me include the build server steps in my build scripts (and thus in source control) rather than as a configuration on the server. This makes migrating to a different server or recovering from disaster more reliable, "documents" this behavior, and allows multiple builds to leverage it without additional configuration. It's several less things people have to remember to set up when they make new build configurations, and it's much easier to write `print '<message>'` than it is to load the build server's web interface and drill through several pages looking for the right configuration page.

I've looked around, but I haven't been able to find anything that does this for Jenkins. Does Jenkins have anything similar?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question somewhere? Thanks!

Comment: :-( Thanks for getting back to me anyway!

Comment: God, I miss TeamCity... compared to which Jenkins is lacking so many great features yet still is the most popular tool... this is bad example of the open-source. Time to switch one more company from J to T!

Comment: @Ivan Honestly, I don't use very many features of TeamCity. I try to keep my processes outside of it, in scripts or what have you. The main reason is that I need to be able to reproduce the build on my local machine when I'm developing, especially when I'm adding new things to it. To me, a build server is primarily a glorified task scheduler that has a good interface for reporting results. One thing I *really* hate about Team City is the licensing model. Since I wrote this question, I took to consolidating my artifacts in a single directory anyway, so I may not even need this feature anymore.

Comment: Well, definitely ability to match local build to CI build is important. And I also try to follow modular approach - there's the right place for everything - something should live in CI tool, something in bespoke scripts, something in between as custom extensions\plugins etc. It's just whatever TC does, it does with much higher reliability and quality than Jenkins, so you don't waste time on maintenance. Licensing - do you mean that you have to pay for it? I think my time wasted on supporting Jenkins is worth much more than TeamCity license. I'd rather pay a little for Enterprise-grade product.

Comment: @Ivan No, I mean how you have to pay for every agent over the first 3. In an environment where you have a lot of disparate projects and would rather keep them separate to avoid each project from stepping on the others' toes, that can get pretty expensive.

Comment: Yes, I know. But I truly believe it's worth it. But as I said I'd rather pay a little and get a reliable Enterprise grade product, that has lots of features out of the box - like the one you mentioned here about service messages. With Jenkins you don't pay money, but you pay with your time - on supporting Jenkins that keeps breaking, on upgrading slaves to new Java versions, on writing custom scripts because there's no standard functionality etc. In TC if you have many projects that don't require constant ability to build, you can unauthorise \ authorise agents to keep number of licenses low.